# css more efficient ? changing color on arrow and header

Tags: html, css, colors, header

So I have three boxes and each box `<h2>` header area has a different color.

Is there a way I can make the arrow below the `<h2>` basically get the color that is selected without making the code too long?

Is there a more efficient way of doing this than making 3 different css codes and 3 different arrow codes for each box?

Basically I want each `<h2>` and arrow to be the same color but with each color selected.

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/mGn9S/

```
<div class="service">
    <div class="service-img">
        <img src="images/img.png" />
    </div>
    <!--end image-->
     <h2 class="service-style color_service">test1</h2>

    <div class="service-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

perfect example in the jsfiddle is box three "Test 3"

Comment: you mean simpler than just making a class for each color? (a la .service-text.orange:before {border-top: 30px solid orange;} for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this more efficient, use CSS preprocessors like [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/) or [**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/).

CSS Solution:

Try:

Add different classes and give border-colors.

HTML:

```
<div class="service-text text1">...
<div class="service-text text2">...
<div class="service-text text3">...
```

CSS:

```
.service-text.text1:before{border-top-color:#2ecc71}
.service-text.text2:before{border-top-color:#e67e22}
.service-text.text3:before{border-top-color:#3498db}
.service-text:before{border-top: 30px solid;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGn9S/1/)

Comment: if i used sass or less as a preprocessor i would need ruby on rails to actually run the sass and or less files right?

Comment: @op1001 no for less you dont need ruby on rails. for sass, I dont have any idea.

Comment: @op1001 SASS requires Ruby on the machine that compiles it, but you just upload the compiled files after that. LESS can either compile locally also, or it has a JS plugin that compiles user-end